# How to design different structures with common parts using inheritance

Tags: c#, json, design-patterns

I've searched a lot about this problem without finding any appreciable result (maybe because i don't have a clear idea of what to ask), then here we are...
I have to design two structures derived from two different JSON which they have  common parts:

```
{
  "data": 
    {
      "success": true,
      "updated_ids": [0],
      "not_updated_ids": [0]
    }
}

{
  "data": 
    {
      "success": true,
      "branch_ids":["0"]
    }
}
```

My idea is to create something like this:

```
class Response
{
    Data data { get; set; }
}

class Data
{
    bool success { get; set; }
}

class UserResponse : Data
{
    List<int> updatedIds { get; set; }
    List<int> notUpdatedIds { get; set; }
}

class BranchResponse : Data
{
    List<string> branchIds { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is: How can i instantiate my two different classes?
If I do `new Response()` i don't get the `UserReponse` or `BranchResponse` part and if i do `new UserResponse()` i don't get the `Response` part.

Basically i would like to instantiate a variable for each structure, populate it with all the values and then Serialize to create the Json.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "I don't get the `Response` part?

Comment: *if i do new UserResponse() i don't get the Response part* No, that's not true at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a part of the suggestion from Andrew i've finally found a solution whihc works for me. Posting it to anyone who maybe is going crazy with it:

```
class Response
{
    Data data { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Data
{
    bool Success { get; set; }
    public abstract Response CreateDeserializationModelSchema();
}

public class UserData : Data
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<int> UpdatedIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> NotUpdatedIds { get; set; }
    public override Response CreateDeserializationModelSchema()
    {
        return new Response
        {
            Data = new UserData()
        };
    }
    public static UsersData GetContent(Response response)
    {
        if (response.Data.GetType() == typeof(UsersData))
            return (UsersData)response.Data;
        else
            throw new FormatException("Response not in the correct format to parse into UpdateUsersStatusResponse");
    }
}

class UsersDataConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Response>
{
    public override Response Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new UsersData().CreateDeserializationModelSchema();
    }
}

public class HowToUseIt
{
    public void Use()
    {
        Response resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonResponse.ToString(), new UserDataConverter());
        UserData u = UserData.GetContent(resp)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright so what you need is an interface and a factory to accomplish what you are trying to create here.

```
public interface IData
{
    bool Success { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public IData Data { get; set; }
}

public class UserData : IData
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<int> UpdatedIds { get; set; }
    public List<int> NotUpdatedIds { get; set; }
}

public class BranchData : IData
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<string> BranchIds { get; set; }
}

public class HowToUseIt
{

    public Response CreateResponse()
    {
        Response myReponse = new Response
        {
            Data = new UserData
            {
                Success = true,
                UpdatedIds = new List<int>(),
                NotUpdatedIds = new List<int>()
            }
        };

        return myReponse;
    }

    public void WhatKindOfDataDoIHave(Response response)
    {
        if (typeof(UserData) == response.Data.GetType())
        {
            //You have user data
        }
        else if (typeof(BranchData) == response.Data.GetType())
        {
            //You have branch data
        }
        else
        {
            //You have a problem!
        }
    }

}
```